# Referencing this custom class with typing

Tags: python, python-typing

I want to define a Node for a Linked List, using type hints. An instance of Node needs a reference to another instance of Node, so I want to accept an optional parameter of type `Node` in my `__init__`.

I tried this:

```py
from typing import Optional

class Node:
    def __init__(self, value: int, next: Optional[Node] = None):
        pass
```

I get an error: `Node is not defined` from `Optional[Node]`.

Comment: `Optional['Node']`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create object inside the same python class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31108208/how-to-create-object-inside-the-same-python-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [How do I type hint a method with the type of the enclosing class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class). You can either:

1. Use `from __future__ import annotations` at the top of the file and then use `Node` as you did.
2. Use a string (`'Node'`), see @Diptangsu Goswami's comment.
3. From Python 3.11 and onwards (not out yet) you will be able to use `from typing import Self` and then `Optional[Self]`.